# Inject into inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance

Is it possible to repurpose a call in an inherited class, I need to do some additional things to the context in `TheFirstClass` prior to and after having `TheLastClass` process the context. Ideally I want to not have to rename the process override in all instances of `TheLastClass`. I tried to just add another abstract class, but the inheritance prevents a second abstract class of the same name.

```
void Main()
{
    var context = new ContextClass();
    var LastClass = new TheLastClass();
    LastClass.CallTheProcess(context);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
abstract class TheBaseClass
{
    public abstract void Process(ContextClass context);

    public void CallTheProcess(ContextClass context)
    {
        // other necessary stuff
        context.test = "Base Class";
        Process(context);
    }
}

class TheFirstClass : TheBaseClass
{   
    //public abstract void Process(ContextClass context)
    public override void Process(ContextClass context)
    {
        context.test = "success";
        Process(context);//How can I call inherited overrides? and not infinite loop
    }
}

class TheLastClass : TheFirstClass
{
    public override void Process(ContextClass context)
    {
        //do stuff with the context
        if(context.test == "success")
        {
            "ThisWorked".Dump();
            //how do I get here?
        }
    }
}

class ContextClass
{
    public string test;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `base` keyword.

```
void Main()
{
    var context = new ContextClass();
    var LastClass = new TheLastClass();
    LastClass.CallTheProcess(context);
}


abstract class TheBaseClass
{
    public abstract void Process(ContextClass context);

    public void CallTheProcess(ContextClass context)
    {
        this.Process(context); 
        // other necessary stuff
        context.test = "Base Class";
    }
}

class TheFirstClass : TheBaseClass
{   
    public override void Process(ContextClass context)
    {
        context.test = "success";
        // some operations
    }
}

class TheLastClass : TheFirstClass
{
    public override void Process(ContextClass context)
    {
        base.Process(context); // from the TheFirstClass
        // other operations
    }
}
```

and then, if you call `LastClass.CallTheProcess(context);` you'll get this order:

1. TheBaseClass.CallTheProcess
2. TheFirstClass.Process
3. TheLastClass.Process (`//other operations` part)

Comment: calling base.Process in TheFirstClass throws "Cannot call an abstract base member: TheBaseClass.Process(UserQuery.ContextClass)'" I need the order to be TheBaseClass.CallTheProcess, TheFirstClass.Process, TheLastClass.Process. Calling base.Process from TheLastClass goes into infinite loop

Comment: I've updated my answer. You're right about the abstract base member. The second issue is because you've made recursive call inTheFirstClass's Process method.

Comment: @KamilPajdzik - I think you're on the right track with this answer, however you've changed the call order from the OP's question. He's calling `CallTheProcess` to kick off the `Process` calls, but you've got `Process` calling `CallTheProcess` in the `TheLastClass`. That seems wrong to me.

Comment: @Enigmativity Ok, I think I've fixed that.

Comment: This will work, it's not as clean as being able to rename the method for the second class to override, but as that isn't possible I think this is a good as it'll be, thanks